# Using NnApiDelegate in TFLite 2.11.0 returns same embeddings for all images. It works fine for 2.6.0

Tags: android, tflite, nnapi

In my android app I'm using Facenet model to recognize faces.
I have added NnApiDelegate to the interpreterOptions.

My app has been working with TFLite version 2.6.0. When I upgraded the TFLite version to 2.10.0 or 2.11.0, I see that the model returns the same embeddings for any image I provide.

Removing the NnApiDelegate works in 2.11.0, but it slows down the face recognition considerably, so I do not want to remove NnApiDelegate. Is there something else that needs to be set for making it work in TFLite 2.11.0?

Code for setting up the interpreter -

```
val interpreterOptions = Interpreter.Options()
interpreterOptions.addDelegate(NnApiDelegate())
interpreter = Interpreter(FileUtil.loadMappedFile(context, model.assetsFilename ) , interpreterOptions)
```

Comment: Hey man, couldn't find any other way to do this, I wanted to know how you are implementing the delegate, I have done so on a similar project but I am getting around 1fps on a Samsung Galaxy S9+... the hardware should be capable of a bit more I believe.